# All electron based apps have stopped working, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center, electron

I'm new to Linux and I've spent the last couple of weeks installing, reinstalling, trying different Desktop Environments, and setting up a personal cloud server.

Along the way the applications I've used have varied, and now that I've finally got my shell etc the way I want it, I've started installing my work and productivity related apps for good.

A lot of these apps are electron because I'm trying to remain as cross platform as possible. I know some of these apps work because on previous installations they worked fine.

But I have started noticing that at some point since my last Re-installation of Ubuntu, all my electron based apps have stopped working.

I think it might have to do with my attempt at building and installing the launcher Hain. It was the only electron app I found that required being built and for some weird reason the node deps wouldn't auto install so I tried going down the tree manually and installing them myself.

I've removed all electron apps from my computer and I've tried to scrub it clean of any left over install of node or npm. But when I reinstall these electron apps they don't work. They don't properly show up in the Software Center installed apps location. Instead they only appear under extensions for some reason and they lack icons. When I try launching them from Software Center, nothing happens.

I tried launching Hyper.js and I can see it in the system monitor but the app itself does not appear.

The same is true of other electron apps. What should I do?